# What is solution set of the given equation and why?

Tags: borel-sets, multisets

**What is the solution set of the below given equation and why?**

> Find the solution set of the equation: $| 7 - x | < 2 , \forall x\in\mathbb R$

**A)** $\{ x \mid x\in\mathbb R, x < 5 \}$

**B)** $\{ x  \mid  x\in\mathbb R, 5 < x < 9 \}$

**C)** $\{ x  \mid  x\in\mathbb R, x < 9 \}$

**D)** $\{ x  \mid  x\in\mathbb R, -5 < x < 9 \}$

Comment: It is not an equation. It is an inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) $x=2, 5<2,$ which is absurd

(C)same absurdity as that of (A)

(D) same absurdity

(B) is the correct one.

Analytical method: $|7-x|=|x-7|<2 \implies -2<x-7<2 \implies 5<x<9.$

Answer (score 0):

Everyone should know from high school that, if $b>0$,
$$|x-a|<b \iff a-b<x<a+b.$$